# How is resource server bounded with auth server in OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth-2.0, authorization

My current auth server doesn't support OAuth 2.0 and I'm trying to set up a new auth server. But I don't need a replacement, I just want to pass the token to my new auth server so it can give access token to a third-party application.

I've been reading many documents about OAuth2 but none of them mentioned how is the access token generated. All of them only said once the user submitted their credential to the authorizaURL, it will verify and send back a code(auth code grant) or an access token(implicit grant).

The problem is, how does the auth server generate that token and how does the resource server verify this token? And how do these two servers bounded together?

Thank you in advance : )

---